# Link error jpeg.lib visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, libjpeg

I have a Visual Studio 2012 console application project where I want to include the jpeg lib (http://www.ijg.org). I downloaded version 9b and I followed these tutorial (http://www.dahlsys.com/misc/compiling_ijg_libjpeg/index.html) .

To use the library…

- I added the “Additional Include Directories” path,
- I added the “Additional Library Directories” path,
- and I added the name of the library to “Input -> Additional
  dependencies”.

If I compile the project, I get a link error “error lnk2001 unresolved external symbol”. I spend the whole day to fix this problem. Finally, I setup a new clean VC project an included only the jpeg lib and afterwards I can compile and run the project. Does anyone know what could be the problem?